# Hover effect won't trigger on a link styled in CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, effect

I have a simple page in which I'm trying to style an a link.  I can style the normal state fine, but the hover state never triggers.

The relevant portion of my stylesheet is:

```
a.faqquestion {
  color: orange;
}

a.faqquestion:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

and my code looks like this:

```
<a onClick="toggleMe('FAQ1')" class="faqquestion">1. How many licenses do I need?</a>
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?  The full page is available at:
http://www.haast.ca/Pages/Products/HAAST/FAQ.htm
and FAQ's 1 and 2 are styled with the class "faqquestion".
Thanks,
Michelle

Comment: Try putting href="#" in the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. cursor should be **pointer** not hand
2. add the faqquestion class to your links
3. your links should have a target so just add a href="/wherever they should go" or href="#"

Comment: Point #3 was the issue!  Although FireFox was ok with it, IE would not work until I had the href in thre.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is ignoring the `a.faqquestion:hover` production because your `cursor` definition is invalid.

Changing `cursor: hand;` to `cursor: pointer;` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The page works fine on my browser, you just forgot to add the class `faqquestion` to the other links

Comment: I'm just testing the first two links...see above for solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Steve_Wellens/tjW6Q/

So, I'm guessing your CSS is in a separate file that's not being loaded.

Comment: nope...it was loading.  It was IE not working when the href value was missing

Answer (score 0):

IT is your just not noticing it because you have nothing changed in the second css, because the HTML tahe < a Come with underline. and try spacing out the different css variable's, like 
a .faqquestion:hove, and it will probably work if you remove the a, because your calling the same tag with two different css tags cause you call the < a with faqquestion

Comment: .faqquestion {
  color: blue;
}

.faqquestion:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: hand;color:red;
}